# PHP manually memory allocation & class/object size

Tags: php, arrays, malloc

Since PHP doesn't provide real arrays, I want to create an array class myself. However, preferably I don't want to create some sort of wrapper class for the PHP array, but I really want to create a real array, like in C/C++. However, if I don't want to use the build in PHP array, I need to have some way to allocate memory manually, and to find the size of an object/class. So I need a PHP version of the c functions sizeof and malloc. Unfortunately, I couldn't find those in PHP. Are there functions which do the same thing, or do you know of any other way to do this?

Edit: I think my question isn't clear enough: 
In PHP an array is really an order map. In some situations this can make things a little more complicated: for example, if you have an array with indices 0,1,2 and 3, you can't relay on that you will get those items in that order in a foreach loop: it depends on the order in which you defined the items in the array. Since those little things annoy me, I want to create a 'real' array class, based on arrays like they are in c/c++. That means that the arrays should have a fixed size, and that I need to allocate memory manually when an array is initialized. For example, when an array of 10 integers is created, the array class should allocate a memory block of the size 10*sizeof(integer). Of course I could use the build in PHP 'array' to store these 10 integers, but than I've just created a wrapper class for the build in array type. So preferably I want to be able to allocate that memory myself so I can manage it in a better way that the build in array type does. However, I couldn't find a function which gives me the size of a class/object, and I could find a function which could allocate memory manually, like malloc does in c.
So my question is: are there any functions for this? And if they aren't, do you have any other efficient ways to achieve my goal?

Comment: `PHP` handles its own memory allocation and garbage collection.  Why do you need to do this?  You can use `memory_get_usage()` to keep track of the current memory usage of the script.

Comment: Because I want some real arrays. And if I'm creating an Array class anyway, I could as well create a good one instead of just some wrapper of the php 'array'.

Comment: what's wrong with PHP arrays?  How are they not real arrays?

Comment: They are ordered hash tables (http://technosophos.com/content/php-arrays-are-not-arrays). And that annoys me. For example, if I want an array with 3 elements, but I first create the element with index 1, than with index 0, and than with index 2, and I use that array in a foreach loop, I will get the item with index 1 before the item with index 0, because it's a hashmap, and not a real array.

Comment: @tandu that means I'll have to use ksort in every function which requires an array. And if you have large arrays it'll be very slow. And this also doesn't force a user to use integer keys correctly, so things can still be messed up (e.g. if someone uses your function but decides to use a string for the key number 1, so we have keys 0,"1" and 2, ksort won't help either (in fact, it'll probably only make things worse)).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4295/discussion-between-tandu-and-tiddo)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PHP already has an [Array Class with `SplFixedArray`](http://php.net/splfixedarray) which *behaves* like you want:

```
$array = new SplFixedArray(3);
$array[1] = 'foo';
$array[0] = 'bar';
$array[2] = 'baz';
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    echo "$k => $v\n";
}
$array[] = 'fails';
```

gives

```
0 => bar
1 => foo
2 => baz
```

and finally

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Index invalid or out of range'

There is a couple of additional [data structures in SPL](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.datastructures.php). For an overview, see

- http://matthewturland.com/2010/05/20/new-spl-features-in-php-5-3/

If you want to know how `SplFixedArray` is implemented in PHP, have a look at

- http://lxr.php.net/opengrok/xref/PHP_TRUNK/ext/spl/spl_fixedarray.c

If you want anything different, you will probably have to implement that at the C level of the language, e.g. you'd have to write your own extension.

Comment: Thanks (again)! That was exactly what I wanted. I should've found that one before!

Comment: Also thanks for those links you added! They are very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure

You could be running out of memory, as your array size is (in theory) only limited by the amount of memory allocated to the script.
Put `ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');`
in the beginning of your script to set the memory limit to 1 GB. You may need to increase this even higher for best results.

Comment: Dont remember malloc as such thats why not sure

Comment: But this still doesn't solve my problem, since I don't have a way to allocate memory manually...